# java.lang.Math.abs not imported by default?

Tags: java, import, static-import

I'm studying for a beginners Java Exam through Oracle.

One of the questions says given:

```
int absoluteValue = abs(-21)
```

What import statement will compile all the code?

Correct answer given as:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

But my question is if `java.lang.*` is imported by default then why is the `Math` class not imported and the `abs()` method not available?

Comment: `import java.lang.*;` != `import static java.lang.Math.*;`

Comment: does java.lang.* not mean all Classes in the lang package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my question is if java.lang.* is imported by default then why is the Math class not imported and the abs method not available?

Because it isn't.

Because that is the way that Java works.  An implicit (or explicit) wildcard import of the classes in a package *only* imports the classes.  It doesn't also do a static import of class members.

If you want to refer to all static members of a class without qualifying them, you should use a wildcard static import; e.g.

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Alternatively you can static import individual members; e.g.

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

---

Why did they define Java this way?

Well it is most likely rationale is that implicit importing makes it harder to read code.  If methods like `abs` get imported by default, then you need to know what they all are ... and where they are imported from ... in order to understand the true meaning of the code.

It is worth knowing that static imports were only added in Java 5.  Prior to that, it was not possible to refer to `Math.abs` without the `Math` qualification.

---

> If you just import the class not its static members then what are you getting when you import it?

You just get the class name.  For example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

allows me to write `new HashMap()` rather than `new java.util.HashMap()` etcetera.  This is significant.  (Imagine if you always had to refer to classes by their full name ....)

Comment: Taking my question a little further , if you just import the class not its static members then what are you getting when you import it?! I mean you don't get the class members so of what use is importing the class if you can't call on methods (or variables?) ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to call `abs()` method on class name of math class `Math.abs()`, It is static method.

or you have to import `import static java.lang.Math.abs;`

**Internal Implementation of `Math` class `absolute()` method.**

```
public static long  abs(long a) {
    return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
 }
```

`abs()` method is `static` method, `java.lang.*;` can not import static member of class.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow `static` method to be imported by default. All methods in [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class are static. That's why these method are not imported by default where all classes from `java.lang.*` package is imported by default.

In addition to `import static java.lang.Math.abs;` - this statement you can use the either of following two -

- `Math.abs()` to directly (without any `import` statement) call the `abs()` method. But this only works for the static method in `java.lang` package, since they are imported by default.
- Or using the following import statement -

`import static java.lang.Math.*;`

In this case you can use the `abs()` method without the class name - `Math`. This technique (static import) will work for all static method of any class under any package.